# Send data using POST method android to PHP?

Tags: java, php, android, http, post

I'm trying to post the 4 variables to a PHP file on a webserver. this is for an android app I'm building in eclipse.

when i open the app the moment it runs this function the app crashes. the app worked fine before i added this function. the app works perfect in the emulator but only on my phone it crashes. i tried running it on both a Samsung S3 and an S2.

Function in the Android app. using the log.d i was able to find out that the app runs up to the try statement than crashes.

```
public void postData( double pLong, double pLat, String timeStamp) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/this.php");
    Log.d("response", "WORKING");
    try {

        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IMEI", deviceid));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LONGITUDE",Double.toString(pLat)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LATITUDE", Double.toString(pLong)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CREATED_AT", timeStamp));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        Log.d("response!!!!", "  " + response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //Requirement Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("response", "nope" + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("response", "nope" + e);
        //Requirement Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
$imei = $_POST['IMEI'];
$long = $_POST['LONGITUDE'];
$lat = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
$time = $_POST['CREATED_AT'];

$con = mysql_connect("host", "username", "password");  //this is the real username and password

if (!$con)
  {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("database", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table`(`imei`, `longitude`, `latitude`, `createdAt`)
VALUES ('".$imei."', '".$long."', '".$lat."', '".$time."')") or die (mysql_error());

$id = mysql_insert_id();
echo "done";
?>
```

Comment: What does the stack trace show?

Comment: which android OS you are using?

Comment: Yet another networkonmainthreadexception question

Comment: Are you using the main thread to POST the data to your PHP server?

Comment: yes I'm trying to post the data to the server. the trace runs up to the  "Log.d("response", "WORKING");" than it crashes. im using android 2.2 on the emulator and 4.0.3 on the phone.

Comment: my guess is you should make it an asynchronous process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new class, instantiate it and .execute().
Why you get this error? because you need to make it asynchronous.

```
private class MyPost extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://cdobiz.com/submit/");

        try {
            // Add your data

            EditText txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBusinessName);
            EditText txtDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("frmName",txtName.getText().toString() ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("frmDesc", txtDesc.getText().toString()));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.v("Post Status","Code: "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```